# ZF2 doctrineORM entity required twice

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Got a zf2 skeleton app, with DoctrineORM with some entities, and all works fine.

Now when i try to add a "Category" entity:

```
namespace Me\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="me_category")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;


    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    protected $name;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = (int)$id;
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = (string) $name;
    }
}
```

but that gives me the following error:

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Cannot redeclare class me\entity\category in App/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php on line 197
```

I figured this was because the Category.php gets required twice.
So i got a temporary fix by adding a "guard" in the Category.php

```
 if (defined('CATEGORY_GUARD')) return;
define('CATEGORY_GUARD', true);
```

This works but of course is not how it's supposed to be done.
Anybody who has any idea why this entity gets required twice?

- i have not used the Category entity anywhere
- the first time it is required as: category.php (normal c) the second time as Category.php (capital C)

Comment: Have you tried clearing any cached meta data?

Comment: Yep no luck, but i think i did kinda found the problem. When i disable ZendDeveloperTools the error goes away..

Comment: Check all other entities that point to category. Make sure the targetEntity is the same for all of them (CamelCase).

Comment: Like i said, it is NOT used anywhere. All i did is create it and i get the error. disabling ZendDeveloperTools fixes it...

Comment: roger. what's the file path and name? Make sure it matches the namespace and class name. The place that's throwing the error essentially looks through the directory and loads all the files inside it.